# How do you check if a field contains all numeric values using Teradata SQL?

Tags: teradata

I'm looking for a function similar to `ISNUMERIC()` from T-SQL with Teradata SQL. I'd like a simple method to return a Boolean (or numeric 1/0) if the data contained in a character-type field is all numeric.

For example:

My column contains the following records: `'001'` and `'ABC'`

I'd expect the query to return: **1 (or True)** and **0 (or False)**.

Is there a method similar to `ISNUMERIC()` natively supported by TD? I found a few options using regex that I could use, but wanted to see if there was a simpler method before going down that path. If such a method doesn't exist, I'm open to suggestions on accomplishing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TD15.10 supports a `TRYCAST('ABC' AS INT)` which returns NULL when the cast fails.

`TO_NUMBER('ABC')` also returns NULL for bad data.

The are some differences for strings like '' or '.': `TRYCAST('' AS INT)` returns `0` and `TO_NUMBER('')` returns `NULL`.

Same for seperators like `-/:`, which are ignored by `trycast`but not by `to_number`: `TryCast('05-075' AS INT)` returns `5075` and `TO_NUMBER` returns `NULL`

You can write a CASE based on that and put it in a SQL UDF.

Comment: This should work perfectly - thanks! I'm new to TD and not sure what version we're on. I don't see trycast as an option, but we do have to_number. I'll just wrap that up in a fn and that.

Comment: @Sevyns: `select * from dbc.dbcinfoV;` shows the actual release.

Comment: where to_number(colname) is null is effective. Dieter to the rescue again.

Answer (score 2):

This will not always work. Please check examples below:

```
SEL TryCast('12-31-2018' AS INT) -- Result: 12312018
SEL TryCast('05-075' AS INT) -- Result: 5075
SEL TryCast('075+' AS INT) -- Result: 75
SEL TryCast('/099' AS INT) -- Result: 99
SEL TryCast('55/55' AS INT) -- Result: 5555
```

Recommended:

```
REGEXP_SIMILAR(TRIM(Value), '^[0-9]{14}$') = 1
```

Comment: Yep, `trycast` uses the same rules in Teradata as CAST (ignoring seperators in FORMAT), so better use `to_number`